# Не работают массивіы

Tags: javascript

Вот собственно данный код должен отображать елемент масива под номером 1.
Но почему то браузер интерпритирует массив как строку и просто выводин один символ из этой строки по номером 1.
Почему так?
В хроме так, в файрфокс.
Эксплоер нормально интерпритирует.

```js
var name = new Array("One", "Two", "Three");
document.write(name[1]);
```

Comment: Поменяй имя переменной. В глобальном контексте name === window.name и автоматически приводится к строке

Comment: А разве массивы не так создаются : var fruits = ["Яблоко", "Апельсин", "Слива"]; Если интересно про массивы , почитай тут : https://learn.javascript.ru/array

Comment: Есть разные способы объявления массивов, да и вообще это не ответ

Comment: Єммм , так в чем проблема сделать другим способом , нужно искать разные решения

Comment: Проблема в том , что все способы не работают. Постоянно видит как строку и все.

Comment: @ДмитрийТерещук Извините, а почему вы откатили уже утвержденную правку? Правка исказила смысл вашего вопроса или были еще какие-то причины? Был вынужден отозвать мой плюс.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Глобальная переменная `name` - конфликт с `window.name`- не работает.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

```js
var name = new Array("One", "Two", "Three");
console.log(typeof name, name);
document.write(name[1]);
```

---

Глобальная переменная с другим именем - работает.

```js
var name1 = new Array("One", "Two", "Three");
console.log(typeof name1, name1);
document.write(name1[1]);
```

---

Локальная переменная `name` - работает.

```js
(function () {
  var name = new Array("One", "Two", "Three");
  console.log(typeof name, name);
  document.write(name[1]);
})();
```

Comment: Да так работает. Я понят, худо что дело в моззиле)